# AWS S3: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to delete uploaded image files with the AWS-SDK-Core Ruby Gem.

I have the following code:

```
require 'aws-sdk-core'

def pull_picture(picture)
    Aws.config = {
        :access_key_id => ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],
        :secret_access_key => ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"],
        :region => 'us-west-2'
    }

    s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new

    test = s3.get_object(
        :bucket => ENV["AWS_S3_BUCKET"],
        :key => picture.image_url.split('/')[-2],   
    )
end
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.

I know the region is correct because if I change it to `us-east-1`, the following error shows up:

> The specified key does not exist.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This happened to me when I accidentally specified the wrong region for the specified bucket.

Answer (score 515, accepted):

It seems likely that this bucket was created in a different region, IE not us-west-2. That's the only time I've seen "The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint."

> US Standard is `us-east-1`

Comment: Never would have thought of that, but it worked for me!  In the AWS SDK, the "US Standard" region seems to be AWSRegionUSEast1.

Comment: Was searching for an answer how to set the region. Thanks!

Comment: If you're using the Ruby client, set `ENV["AWS_REGION"]` to the correct value (e.g. `"us-east-1"`) for the bucket before initializing the client

Comment: What if you need to use more than one bucket (e.g. dev/staging/production etc)?

Comment: I had the same problem in Java. Your solution helped. They use strange names in S3. *Endpoint* for region, *key* for object name in the repository...

Comment: Northern California appears to be us-west-1, not us-west-2 - that was my mistake.

Comment: I had the same problem in .net. Changing RegionEndpoint did the magic.

Comment: If you just ran into this issue with Cyberduck in 9/2021, even if your bucket actually is in us-west-1, use use-east-1 and the problem will go away as answered on this. Not very clear error message as far as Cyberduck is showing.

Comment: I faced the same problem while creating API gateway to upload media in s3 bucket. steps provided in (https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-upload-image-s3/). First, I used a bucket in the us-east-1 region, but after changing it to us-west-2 it worked.

Comment: This API is incredibly bad, I can't believe this is still an issue 10 years later

Comment: Found this question with the same problem... still can't get it to work!

Answer (score 29):

I was facing a similar error because the bucket was in region `us-west-2` and the URL pattern had bucketname in the path. Once, I changed the URL pattern to have bucketname as URL subdomain to grab the files and it worked.

For eg previous URL was

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/filePath/filename
```

Then I replaced it as

```
https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/filePath/filename
```

Comment: Putting the fully qualified name worked for me Eg. https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/ng-spark/Java8.json for the bucket which is in Singapore availability zone

Answer (score 26):

Check your bucket location in the console, then use this as reference to which endpoint to use:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region

Comment: Can you explain how?
Replace `region: 'us-west-1',` with what?

Comment: @AamirAfridi it depends on which SDK you're using. I'm using iOS SDK, and in the credential provider, there's a parameter where you can set the region. I've set that to the region I intend to use.

Comment: I just had a similar example, where I optimised the region of a bucket, but I ommitted to update the domain name. The fix was to replace the previous domain name with the new one, as seen in the endpoint reference in the S3 console for that bucket. Example: I replaced `https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/myasset.jpg` with `https://mybucket.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/myasset.jpg` to fix that error.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I selected wrong RegionEndpoint. After selecting the correct RegionEndpoint, it started working :)

Answer (score 7):

After a long search, I found a working solution. The issue was because of the wrong `region-code`.

below is the list of region-codes, set the appropriate one and your issue will be solved.

```
Code                         Name
US East (Ohio)               us-east-2

US East (N. Virginia)       us-east-1

US West (N. California)     us-west-1

US West (Oregon)            us-west-2

Asia Pacific (Hong Kong)    ap-east-1

Asia Pacific (Mumbai)       ap-south-1

Asia Pacific (Osaka-Local)  ap-northeast-3

Asia Pacific (Seoul)        ap-northeast-2

Asia Pacific (Singapore)    ap-southeast-1

Asia Pacific (Sydney)       ap-southeast-2

Asia Pacific (Tokyo)        ap-northeast-1

Canada (Central)            ca-central-1

Europe (Frankfurt)          eu-central-1

Europe (Ireland)            eu-west-1

Europe (London)             eu-west-2

Europe (Paris)             eu-west-3

Europe (Stockholm)         eu-north-1

Middle East (Bahrain)      me-south-1

South America (São Paulo)   sa-east-1
```

You can find your region-code on click of bucket name right corner.

[image]

For mode details [Click](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html)

Answer (score 7):

For those of you using `@aws-sdk/client-s3`, just be sure to supply the bucket's region to the client before you send the command.
Get it with the CLI:

```
$ aws s3api get-bucket-location --bucket <bucket_name>
{
    "LocationConstraint": "ca-central-1"
}
```

```
const client = new S3Client({ region: "ca-central-1", credentials...
```

Comment: Region is also visible in AWS console in the Properties tab, Bucket overview
section of the bucket or any of the sub folders.

Comment: Yeah got burned by this when migrations some v2 AWS SDK code to v3. My lambda@edge function was working some of the time, and other times not working, turns out it was because I didn't manually set the region in the s3 config because the region your lambda function executes in isn't guaranteed for lambda@edge.

Answer (score 4):

Though S3 bucket is global but while accessing bucket we need to give region. I was getting error in .netcore, Once I added region in below code, it start working.

```
var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USWest2);
```

Answer (score 4):

In C# you can do a following check, I assume, similar code is possible with other SDKs:

```
        var client = new AmazonS3Client(
            credentials.AccessKey,
            credentials.ClientSecret,
            new AmazonS3Config{}
        );

        var bucketLocationRequest = new GetBucketLocationRequest
        {
            BucketName = amazonS3Bucket.BucketName
        };

        var response = await client.GetBucketLocationAsync(bucketLocationRequest);
        var region = response.Location;

        var regionEndpoint = region != null ? RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(region.Value) : RegionEndpoint.EUCentral1;
       
        var clientWithRegion = new AmazonS3Client(
            credentials.AccessKey,
            credentials.ClientSecret,
            new AmazonS3Config
            {
                RegionEndpoint = regionEndpoint
            }
        );
```

Comment: I ended up on this question when looking for solution for .NET, so I assume it could be usueful for other people.

Answer (score 3):

None of the above answers fixed my issue.

The above answers are probably more likely the cause of your problem but my issue was that I was using the wrong bucket name.  It was a valid bucket name, it just wasn't my bucket.

The bucket I was pointing to was in a different region that my lambda function so check your bucket name!

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this issue when using a different AWS profile. I saw the error when I was using an account with admin permissions, so the possibility of permissions issues seemed unlikely.

It's really a pet peeve of mine that AWS is so prone to issuing error messages that have such little correlation with the required actions, from a user perspective.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the bucket name was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

For many S3 API packages (I recently had this problem the [npm s3 package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3)) you can run into issues where the region is assumed to be US Standard, and lookup by name will require you to explicitly define the region if you choose to host a bucket outside of that region.

Answer (score 2):

For ppl who are still facing this issue, try adding s3_host as follows to the config hash

```
   :storage => :s3,
   :s3_credentials => {:access_key_id => access key,
   :secret_access_key => secret access key},
   :bucket => bucket name here,
   :s3_host_name => s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com or whatever comes as per your region}.
```

This fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had same error. It occurred when s3 client was created with different endpoint than the one which was set up while creating bucket.

- ERROR CODE - The bucket was set up with EAST Region.

s3Client = New AmazonS3Client(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY, RegionEndpoint.USWest2)

- FIX

s3Client = New AmazonS3Client(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY, RegionEndpoint.**USEast1**)

Answer (score 2):

Look at your aws-exports config file, there should already me a region, just selected the same region.

mine was: `"aws_project_region": "us-east-2"`

So I put `region: 'us-east-2'`

Worked for me.

Comment: I had wrong region name that caused me this error :-)

Answer (score 1):

During the creation of S3Client you can specify the endpoint mapping to a particular region. If default of `s3.amazonaws.com` then bucket will be created in `us-east-1` which is North Virginia.

More details on S3 endpoints and regions in AWS docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region.

So, always make sure about the endpoint/region while creating the S3Client and access S3 resouces using the same client in the same region.

If the bucket is created from AWS S3 Console, then check the region from the console for that bucket then create a S3 Client in that region using the endpoint details mentioned in the above link.

Answer (score 1):

I Have faced the same issue.After a lot of struggle I found that the real issue is with the com.amazonaws dependencies.After adding dependencies this error got disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I got this exception on c#.net, It was fixed after changing the RegionEndpoint value on client creation as below

```
var client = new AmazonS3Client(accesKey,secretKey, RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast2)
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked with following end point:

https://bucketname.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/

Be sure to put your correct region and bucket name.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I tried to access a bucket that didn't exist.

I mistakenly switched a path variable with the bucket name variable and so the bucket name had the file path value. So maybe double-check, if the bucket name that you set on your request is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I live in uk was keep on trying for 'us-west-2'region. So redirected to 'eu-west-2'. The correct region for S3 is 'eu-west-2'

Answer (score 0):

This occurred for me when I had a source ip constraint on the policy being used by the user (access key / secret key) to create the s3 bucket.  My IP was accurate--but for some reason it wouldn't work and gave this error.

Answer (score 0):

"Base End Point" should be wrong.

as I renamed AWS Region
http://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
to
http://s3.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com
its fixed.
my request was "ListBuckets"

Answer (score 0):

```
Had the same issue when executing gitlab pipeline with Terraform. Resolved by adding correct provider region to provider.tf

terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 5.0"
    }
    awscc = {
      source  = "hashicorp/awscc"
      version = "~> 0.1"
    }
  }

provider "awscc" {
  region = "Region of s3 bucket"
}
```