# django-storages - ImproperlyConfigured: Could not load amazon's s3 bindings

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, django-storage

I feel so dumb now

I am trying to use [django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html)

I installed

```
pip install django-storages
```

then, added `'storages',` into settings.py

then in settings.py

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3.S3Storage'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'xxx'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'yyy'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'mybucketname'
```

and tried to see if default file storage is changed:

```
>>> from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
>>> print default_storage.connection
....
ImproperlyConfigured: Could not load amazon's s3 bindings.
```

what am I missing

Comment: Do you have `boto` installed? Does installing it make any difference? Thanks.

Comment: `pip install boto` ^^ just to piggy back

Comment: @jape I did, not a single sign of success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html#usage):

> There are two backend APIs for interacting with S3. The first is the
>   s3 backend (in storages/backends/s3.py) which is simple and *based on
>   the Amazon S3 Python library*.

and the [source code](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/blob/1.1.9/storages/backends/s3.py#L16):

```
try:
    from S3 import AWSAuthConnection, QueryStringAuthGenerator, CallingFormat
except ImportError:
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Could not load amazon's S3 bindings.\nSee "
        "http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=134")
```

The `storages.backends.s3.S3Storage` backend requires the [Amazon `S3` library](https://aws.amazon.com/items/134?externalID=134) to be installed.

<sub>I might confuse the original library and the fork, but I think the point stays valid.</sub>

Comment: thanks Alex, i downloaded the file from the link and now it is working

Comment: now I am getting `The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint`  because my bucket is in frankfurt but it is a different problem.. ( or any ideas? :) ) ?

Comment: @doniyor yeah, it's probably this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027462/aws-s3-the-bucket-you-are-attempting-to-access-must-be-addressed-using-the-spec.