# Uploading to a Signed AWS S3 Put URL returns a "Permanent Redirect "

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

My goal is to create a Lamda function that does some permission checking (via external API) then signs a URL to allow uploads to S3.

I created the following AWS lambda function:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var uuid = require('uuid');
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    // Some Auth Code is here to make sure user has permission
    var s3 = new AWS.S3();
    var url = s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', {
      Bucket: config.uploadBucket,
      Key: event.partnerName + '/images/' + uuid.v4()
    });
    context.succeed(JSON.stringify({
      url: url
    }));
}
```

I get back a URL!

https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/PATH/images/3f7ff785-1868-4a54-9ae2-e94228d4868d?AWSAccessKeyId=....&Expires=1455124250&Signature=...&x-amz-security-token=...

Then I created a JSBin to test it

```
<form method="POST" action="THE_URL_I_GOT">
  <input name="file" type="file"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
  </form>
```

But when I tried to upload a file I got

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>PermanentRedirect</Code>
    <Message>The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.</Message>
    <Bucket>MYBUCKETNAMEHERE</Bucket>
    <Endpoint>s3.amazonaws.com</Endpoint>
    <RequestId>...</RequestId>
    <HostId>.....</HostId>
</Error>
```

**EDIT**
Also it turns out that I can't upload a file as a multipart form. Instead I have to use XMLHttpRequest to send the file as a Binary to the signed url (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node#direct-uploading)

Comment: are you sure the bucket is in us-west-2? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027462/aws-s3-the-bucket-you-are-attempting-to-access-must-be-addressed-using-the-spec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your bucket is in the US Standard region.

You need to generate a pre-signed upload URL using the US Standard endpoint.

Comment: That worked. Changed the region using `AWS.config.update()` to us-east-1.  Now I'm getting an error: "SignatureDoesNotMatchThe request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.ASIAI4I5NAPUWOULKMIQPOST multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryqKDFP6teTQvBCLYS 1455133079 x-amz-security-token:...

Comment: Make sure that the access key or IAM role that is active while generating your pre-signed URL is valid. Also, make sure that your pre-signed URL isn't being altered or "damaged" somehow by URL encoding, etc.

Comment: Hmm...Do you know what permissions I need to sign a put request? I gave it the standard s3_exec role (works when I manually call the `upload` function) `"Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::*"
      ] `

Comment: The pre-signed URL has the same permissions as the credentials used to generate it. So if your main one works, then the pre-signed URL should work with the same permissions.

Comment: You're signing a URL for `putObject` but your form is for `POST`... so the mismatch error is correct, because the signature does not match the request that is being made. You can't `PUT` an object with a `POST` request, and uploading files through a form requires an entirely different signing mechanism, involving the inclusion of a signed policy.