# react - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource when fetching the images from s3

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

```
import imageToBase64 from 'image-to-base64';
...

formatImageToBase64 = () => {
   imageToBase64("https://example.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/images/image1") // Path to the image
       .then(
           (response) => {
               console.log(response);
           }
       )
       .catch(
           (error) => {
               console.log(error); 
           }
       )
}
```

When I run this function, error occurs as below.

```
Access to fetch at 'example.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/images/image1?AWSAccessKeyId=qwertyuip12344&Expires=1664366635&Signature=aoqogfjfj3%2Foofofol%3D' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled
```

I checked my S3 setting but it seems no problem.

[image]
I also tried to change the AllowedOrigin to '*', but still not working.

Comment: I would take a deeper look at _AllowedOrigins_ as I'm pretty sure _localhost_ is not what you want

Answer (score 0):

Try `<AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>` instead of your `localhost` and check if it works - if it does then you know the problem is within `AllowedOrigin` rule.

For more detailed description how to define your CORS just take a look at: [S3 - Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533888/s3-access-control-allow-origin-header)

UPDATE: I've tried to access the link you've provided and what I've got in return is a following message "The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint".
You can follow it up at: [AWS S3: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027462/aws-s3-the-bucket-you-are-attempting-to-access-must-be-addressed-using-the-spec)

Comment: Originally, I was using <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>, but it didn't work