# S3Exception: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, kotlin, amazon-s3, heroku

I know that there are many similar questions, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027462/aws-s3-the-bucket-you-are-attempting-to-access-must-be-addressed-using-the-spec) is no exception

But unfortunately I can't decide on the region for my case, how can I decide on the right region?

For example, when making a request to Postman, I encounter a similar error:
[image]

In my console i'm using `EU (Frankfurt) eu-central-1` and also in terminal write smth like this:

```
heroku config:set region="eu-central-1"
```

And as I understand it, mine does not fit.

Also here is my AWS class:

```
class AmazonFileStorage : FileStorage {

    private val client: S3Client

    private val bucketName: String = System.getenv("bucketName")

    init {
        val region = System.getenv("region")
        val accessKey = System.getenv("accessKey")
        val secretKey = System.getenv("secretKey")

        val credentials = AwsBasicCredentials.create(accessKey, secretKey)
        val awsRegion = Region.of(region)
        client = S3Client.builder()
            .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(credentials))
            .region(awsRegion)
            .build() as S3Client
    }

    override suspend fun save(file: File): String =
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            client.putObject(
                PutObjectRequest.builder().bucket(bucketName).key(file.name).acl(ObjectCannedACL.PUBLIC_READ).build(),
                RequestBody.fromFile(file)
            )
            val request = GetUrlRequest.builder().bucket(bucketName).key(file.name).build()
            client.utilities().getUrl(request).toExternalForm()
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have the wrong region code; you do know that a Bucket is available in one and only one Region?

In your logging settings, set this scope to debug:

```
logging:
  level:
    org.apache.http.wire: debug
```

Then you should see something like this:

```
http-outgoing-0 >> "HEAD /somefile HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: YOURBUCKETNAME.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com[\r][\n]"
```

That log is from a bucket in the London region `eu-west-2`